# *beginner Why is this grid layout not working for html? i cant figure out

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

i learned the basics of grid layout today and got one to work but i cant figure out why this is not working.

At the moment i cant figure out why. Any help will be much appreciated.
here is my HTML code:

```
  <div id="PromiseImpactArea">
<span id="promiseTitle">Our Promise:</span>
<div id="promiseArea">{{currentCharity.promise}}</div>
```

```
 #promiseImpactArea{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows: [row1-start] 40px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-template-areas:
    "promiseTitle promiseTitle promiseArea promiseArea";
}

#promiseTitle {
  border: solid 2px red;
  grid-area: promiseTitle;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#promiseArea {
  grid-area: promiseArea;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid tomato;
}
```

Comment: How do you untimely want this to look? Can you describe it?

Comment: hi there Andy, i was trying to put a div along with carousel in same line but b.c carousel was not working i tried with this simpler example. I couldnt figure out why something simple like having 2 divs in one column wasnt working. @Grms thankfully pointed out that it was capitalization error and now working on carousel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that not working with a capital P on first css line ?

Comment: LOL, you got it!! thankyou so much.... I cant believe it was due to capitalization error.Thankyou Again!!!